# How to remove special characters and leading zeros from field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have field that has something like this 083_33:152#7 0100 and i want to remove all the special characters, spaces, leading and trailing zeros etc at one time.  How can i do that?  the output should be like this:
8333152701
here is what i have

```
select * from myTable where REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(part_number, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') =  '8333152701'
```

the query should return this: 8333152701
Thanks

Comment: you have 2 replaces...keep on adding more replaces? whats your question...

Comment: Do you know in advance what special chars will you have? Also, what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: i am using sql server 2012 and also maybe , and ; and : need to be removed just in case

Comment: If you have MSSQL 2016 you could write some inline `R` to regex.  Or 2017 you can use inline `python`

Comment: SQL-Server should have a translate function where you specify an array to get replaced with the same value.

Comment: @Error_2646 [SQL Server 2017 does. Not 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @MartinSmith. No translate and no regex. Bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Alan for the detail, it is really great.  i am just posting this if anyone needs a simplified version.

```
select * from myTable 
where replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(isnull(part_number,''),'-',''),'-',''),'*',''),' ',''),'.',''),',',''),'/',''),'\',''),'#',''),':',''),'''',''),'(',''),')',''))), '0', ' '))), ' ', '0') = '8333152701'
```

Comment: It is great, if this works for you, but this is not a *simplified version*, at least not for your requirement (*i want to remove all the special characters, spaces, leading and trailing zeros etc at one time*). It is limited to a very small set of *special characters*... This might work, but does not answer the question...

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important then the fastest function for stripping non-numeric characters is [DigitsOnlyEE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/) (you can get the code by clicking the link). A complete solution that trims leading/trailing 0's and spaces would look like this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = '083_33:152#7 0100';

SELECT de.digitsOnly
FROM (VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(@string)))) f(s)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(    -- string, substring start, substring stop, string datalength:
  PATINDEX('%[^0]%',f.s),PATINDEX('%[^0]%',REVERSE(f.s)),LEN(f.s))) f2(ss,sstp,ds) 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(f.s, f2.ss, f2.ds+1-f2.sstp-(f2.ss-1)))) trimmed(string)
CROSS APPLY dbo.digitsOnlyEE(trimmed.string) de;
```

What @shnugo posted can be fast provided that:
1. You turn it into an inline table valued function
2. Run it with a parallel execution plan

Note that, as-is the function returns `050` when the string is `BDA505AD000FAC` my understanding is that you should get: `505000` but I'm sure there's a quick fix for that. Anyhow, the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getonlynumbers(@v VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@v,1,1)) BETWEEN ASCII(0) AND ASCII(9) THEN SUBSTRING(@v,1,1) ELSE '' END AS Chr
          ,1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1)) BETWEEN ASCII(0) AND ASCII(9) THEN SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1) ELSE '' END
          ,r.Pos+1
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE r.Pos<=LEN(@v)
)
,GetOnlyNumbers(CleanedString) AS
(
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT Chr AS [*]
        FROM recCTE
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(100)')
)
SELECT REVERSE(B.CleanedFromRear) AS CleanedNumber
FROM GetOnlyNumbers
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(CleanedString,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',CleanedString),1000) AS CleanedFromFront) A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CleanedFromFront),PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REVERSE(CleanedFromFront)),1000) AS CleanedFromRear) B
```

Now for a performance test. First the sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#strings') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #strings;

DECLARE @default VARCHAR(100) = '083_33:152#7 0100';
SELECT TOP (10000)
  string = 
    ISNULL(CAST(
      REPLICATE('  ', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%2))+
      REPLICATE('0',  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%4))+
      REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(NEWID(),12),'-','000'),'9', f.rnd)+
      REPLICATE('0',  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%4)) AS VARCHAR(100)),@default)
INTO #strings 
FROM sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns b
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT TOP (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%5)) f.C+''
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (31) 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))^32,
    CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))^32)
    FROM sys.all_columns) f(N,C)
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  FOR XML PATH('')
) f(rnd);
```

... next for the performance test. The benefit of inline table valued functions is that they can run with a serial and parallel execution plan. For this test with a serial and parallel execution plan.

```
PRINT 'getonlynumbers - Serial'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',60)
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @x = f.cleanedNumber
FROM #strings s
CROSS APPLY dbo.getonlynumbers(s.string) f
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3

PRINT 'getonlynumbers - parallel'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',60)
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @x = f.cleanedNumber
FROM #strings s
CROSS APPLY dbo.getonlynumbers(s.string) f
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3

PRINT 'DigitsOnlyEE - Serial'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',60)
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @x = de.digitsOnly
FROM #strings s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(s.string)))) f(s)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(    -- string, substring start, substring stop, string datalength:
  PATINDEX('%[^0]%',f.s),PATINDEX('%[^0]%',REVERSE(f.s)),LEN(f.s))) f2(ss,sstp,ds) 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(f.s, f2.ss, f2.ds+1-f2.sstp-(f2.ss-1)))) trimmed(string)
CROSS APPLY dbo.digitsOnlyEE(trimmed.string) de
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3

PRINT 'DigitsOnlyEE - parallel'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',60)
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @x = de.digitsOnly
FROM #strings s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(s.string)))) f(s)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(    -- string, substring start, substring stop, string datalength:
  PATINDEX('%[^0]%',f.s),PATINDEX('%[^0]%',REVERSE(f.s)),LEN(f.s))) f2(ss,sstp,ds) 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(f.s, f2.ss, f2.ds+1-f2.sstp-(f2.ss-1)))) trimmed(string)
CROSS APPLY dbo.digitsOnlyEE(trimmed.string) de
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3
```

And the results:

```
getonlynumbers - Serial
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
2007
2037
2153
Batch execution completed 3 times.

getonlynumbers - parallel
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
513
466
510
Batch execution completed 3 times.

DigitsOnlyEE - Serial
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
250
266
233
Batch execution completed 3 times.

DigitsOnlyEE - parallel
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
63
64
70
Batch execution completed 3 times.
```

Comment: Alan, thx for your comprehensive answer. Yes, this function is faster than my approach. But keep in mind, that it will not get rid of leading and trailing zeros. And one more hint. You might prefer `DATETIME2` and `SYSUTCDATETIME()` for time measurements. Anyway, +1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

Not really like the answer (because of the nested replace), but this seems to be a solution:

```
select * from myTable where replace(replace(replace(replace(trim('0 _:#' FROM part_number), '_',''),':',''),'#',''),' ','')='8333152701'
```

Trim does only remove start and ending characters, but you seem to also want to remove characters in the middle. For each character I have a nested replace.

Comment: there is syntax error, there are 2 from in the query

Comment: [trim is another SQL Server 2017 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all characters, which are not a digit:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)='083_33:152#7 0100';

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@v,1,1)) BETWEEN ASCII(0) AND ASCII(9) THEN SUBSTRING(@v,1,1) ELSE '' END AS Chr
          ,1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1)) BETWEEN ASCII(0) AND ASCII(9) THEN SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1) ELSE '' END
          ,r.Pos+1
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE r.Pos<=LEN(@v)
)
SELECT
(
    SELECT Chr AS [*]
    FROM recCTE
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(100)');
```

The solution uses a *recursive CTE* to walk along the string. Each single character is checked if it is a number. The result is concatenated using `FOR XML`.

### UPDATE: Full solution with cleaning of leading and ending zeros:

### EDIT: Removed unecessary coplications

The easiest way to remove the leading and trailing zeros was to replace them with blanks and use `LTRIM(RTRIM())` to get rid of the leading and trailing blanks. Then to replace the internal blanks with zeros.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getonlynumbers(@v VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@v,1,1)='0' THEN ' '
                WHEN SUBSTRING(@v,1,1) BETWEEN '1' AND '9' THEN SUBSTRING(@v,1,1) 
                ELSE '' END AS Chr
          ,1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1)='0' THEN ' '
                WHEN SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1) BETWEEN '1' AND '9' THEN SUBSTRING(@v,r.Pos+1,1)
                ELSE '' END AS Chr
              ,r.Pos+1
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE r.Pos<=LEN(@v)
)
,GetOnlyNumbers(CleanedString) AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(
    (
        SELECT Chr AS [*]
        FROM recCTE
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(8000)'))),' ','0')
)
SELECT CleanedString 
FROM GetOnlyNumbers;
```